# how to grab biggest value using only foreach loop?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

how  to grab biggest value using only foreach loop?

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<DateTime>();
        list.Add(new DateTime(1980, 5, 12));
        list.Add(new DateTime(1960, 1, 2));
        list.Add(new DateTime(1983, 5, 4));
        list.Add(new DateTime(1999, 10, 11));
        list.Add(new DateTime(1913, 4, 7));

        foreach(var date in list)
        {




        };
    }

}
```

how do i return the 'biggest'(latest) date?

Comment: This should be tagged as homework..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Nope, the homework tag is deprecated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 5):

`list.Max()` will give you the maximum date time object from your list. Why do you want to use a foreach loop here anyway ?

**Edit**: Added a simple foreach logic as well since the OP asked for it.

```
var maxDate = new DateTime(); // initialize to a zero value. 
foreach (var date in list)
{
    if (date > maxDate)
    {
        maxDate = date;
    }
};
```

Comment: So a homework question? LEARN, do not have others do your work, or you end up at McDonalds serving burgers with a CS diploma you have no clue how to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use your foreach loop you can use a temporary variable to keep track of the current largest value.

```
 var list = new List<DateTime>();
 list.Add(new DateTime(1980, 5, 12));
 list.Add(new DateTime(1960, 1, 2));
 list.Add(new DateTime(1983, 5, 4));
 list.Add(new DateTime(1999, 10, 11));
 list.Add(new DateTime(1913, 4, 7));

 DateTime max = DateTime.MinValue;

 foreach (DateTime d in list)
 {
     if (d > max)
         max = d;
 }
```

But as ryadavilli suggested, it's easier to use LINQ (Language Integrated Query). Linq is a set of extensions to all the collection types in the .NET Framework. You can use these by putting a `using System.Linq` statement at the top of your file.

Comment: Looks like a homework question on usage of loops, rather than on C# and .Net usage.